# Multiple different types of exception handling in one catch block?

Tags: java

If Multiple exceptions are allowed in catch() then it will reduce amount of redundant  error handling code.
for example,

```
try{
// some statments 
}
catch(Type1Exception t1, Type2Exception t2, Type3Exception t3) {   // wish if this could be allowed
/* t1, t2, t3 are children of Exception and needs same error handling then why to have different catch blocks with same piece of code */
}
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: @Closer: I really don't understand people who vote to close a question because they don't see a question mark in it! Come on, this is an interesting question!

Comment: @Armen: It's not really clear what the actual *question* is here. On the other hand, I'm hoping my answer will address whatever the intended question actually was...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes - that's why it's [supported in Java 7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html).

So your example would actually be:

```
try {
} catch (Type1Exception | Type2Exception | Type3Exception ex) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: No, he means `|`. :-)  The tutorial says: "In the catch clause, specify the types of exceptions that block can handle, and separate each exception type with a vertical bar (|)"

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Is there something similar in .NET, (prev or upcoming version)?

Comment: @VoodooChild: It would be a language feature, not a platform feature. I don't know of anything equivalent in any .NET language though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I didn't know of this feature of Java 7. Great improvement!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: what's the type of `ex`? It's not mentioned in the link you provided, but I assume is a common super-type? Or just `Exception`, or `Throwable`?

Comment: Thanks Jon for this answer. I almost completed JSR documentation for this request but didn't submit it. 
I wanted to have this feature. And now in Java 7, its there... Pleasant Surprise indeed!!! Thanks Jon for letting me know.

Comment: @Jordão The 'ex' you mentioned is an object of class Exception, subclass of Throwable.